# How to delete multiple rows in data frame at panda in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas to make a dataframe. I want to delete **12 initial rows** by drop function. every resources website says that you should use drop to delete the rows unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't know why. the error says that **'list' object has no attribute 'drop'** could you do me a favor and find it what should I do?

```
url=Exp01.html
url=str(url)
df = pd.read_html(url)
df = df.drop(index=['1','12'],axis=0,inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas read_html returns a *list* of dataframes.
So df is a list on your example. First, take a look at what the list holds.
If it's just one table (dataframe), you can change it to:

```
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Full code:

```
url=Exp01.html
url=str(url)
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df.drop(index=df.index[:12], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: why I can not delete first 12 row with drop? what should I do?

Comment: @saiedvaygani, added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the rows out:

```
df = df.loc[11:]
df
```

loc in general is configured this way:

```
df.loc[x:y]
```

where x is the starting index and y is the ending index.
[11:] gives starting index as 11 and no ending index